# Change an image on click with Javascript, but still following the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, click, src

I have the following html

`<a href="email.html" target="_blank" ><img src="../img/mailto.gif" alt="Send email" id='email'/></a>`

Clicking the image should open a new window and you should now if that image has been clicked on before, simply because it would change when you click on it.
This is also included in a table created with PHP from a MySQL table (basically, this means I will get a new image in every row and I can only change their ID's globally, not one by one..)

After adding this jquery code the link stopped working. Which means that, when I click on the image it changes to a different one (.../img/mailto_onclick.gif) and that's fine, but the email.html page doesnt open in a new tab like it used to...

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#email').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',"../img/mailto_onclick.gif");
       return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Any thought's on how to get this working?
Sorry if it's some basic or obvious stuff

Comment: because of ``return false`` it is stopping default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#email').click(function(){

        $(this).attr('src',"../img/mailto_onclick.gif");
           //return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return false` as it will prevent the default behavior for `click()` because `<img>` is wrapped inside `<a></a>`.

```
 $('#email').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',"../img/mailto_onclick.gif");
      // return false; // remove
  });
```